# copying values from a integer array to integer struct

Tags: c, memory-management

I have an integer array:

```
 int num[20] = {1,1,5,5,1,1,5,9,2,2,6,1,1,2,5,5,1,3,6,2};
```

I want to copy the elements `num` into the following struct:

```
struct tuple
{
int p1;
int p2;
int p3;
int p4;
};
```

I am doing the following:

```
struct tuple *arr;
memcpy(&arr,&num,sizeof(num));
```

This does not seem to work, since I am encountering a segmentation fault later on in the code.
When I try to print the size:

```
printf("size of arr: %lu, size of arr[0]: %lu \n", sizeof(arr), sizeof(arr[0]));
```

I get the following:

```
size of arr: 8, size of arr[0]: 16
```

which is wrong, since the values should read:

```
size of arr: 80, size of arr[0]: 16
```

Therefore when I try to print, it seg faults:

```
for (i=0;i<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);++i)
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n", arr[i].p1,arr[i].p2, arr[i].p3, arr[i].p4);
```

Can someone assist me as to where I might be going wrong?

Comment: You can't `memcpy` to an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Also, `arr` is a pointer, that that is eight bytes large is not surprising.

Comment: @chris The argument to `memcpy` is the address of the pointer. Not sure whether that's worse or better than an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: You were really wanting to do `memcpy(arr,num,sizeof(num));` vs. `memcpy(&arr,&num,sizeof(num));`  But the are many other problems than this.  Need new approach.

Comment: Strange is that you _need_ such a copying at all. What are you trying to achieve? The chances are high that there is a more appropriate way to do it.

Comment: @chux, If you were going to use `memcpy`, better to make an object and pass the address of it.

Comment: @chris True, `arr` needs a valid value before calling `memcpy()`.  Tagging as [c] and [c++] confuses the preferred allocating paradigm.  There are so many issues here with this post.

Comment: You're copying 20 things into 4 things.  What do you *mean*?

Answer (score 3):

Several points to make here.  Firstly:

```
struct tuple *arr;
memcpy(&arr,&num,sizeof(num));
```

`arr` is a *pointer* to a `struct tuple`; it is not a `struct tuple`, and it's size is the pointer size on your system (which is probably 8 bytes), not the same size as a `struct tuple`.  When you do the `memcpy`, it's copying over *the pointer to `struct tuple`*, not a `struct tuple` instance.

Secondly, if you meant to copy to a `struct tuple` like this:

```
struct tuple aTuple;
memcpy(&aTuple,&num,sizeof(num));
```

Then you would have an actual instance of a `struct tuple` rather than just a pointer, and the memcpy would copy to that memory.  But this *would still be wrong* because:

1)  The size of the array is much larger than the size of `struct tuple`, and

2)  Structures are not guaranteed to have all their fields adjacent in memory.  There can be padding between `p1` and `p2`, etc., so the structure and the array would be arranged in memory differently and not directly copyable.

Incidentally, this would work for memcpy to a `struct tuple`:

```
struct tuple aTuple;
aTuple.p1 = aTuple.p2 = aTuple.p3 = aTuple.p4 = 42;
struct tuple anotherTuple;
memcpy(&anotherTuple,&aTuple,sizeof(struct tuple));
```

I post that only as an example of correct usage.

EDIT:

Another thing, regarding this:

```
printf("size of arr: %lu, size of arr[0]: %lu \n", sizeof(arr), sizeof(arr[0]));
```

Did you pass `num` to another function, as parameter `arr`?  In that case the `arr` is also a pointer, whose size is 8 rather than 80.  When you pass an array to a function, it is passed as a pointer.

Comment: It looks to me like `arr` is his `struct tuple *`, which means it's a pointer to `tuple`s and therefore the sizeof() quotient trick won't work.  If `arr` were `struct tuple[5]`, though, it would be fine (provided, of course, it weren't passed through a function and decayed to a pointer, as you mention).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `struct tuple *arr;` with `struct tuple arr[5];` or perhaps `struct tuple arr[sizeof(num)/sizeof(struct tuple)];`.  When you declare `arr` as a pointer, it doesn't allocate any space for the array it's pointing to.  When you declare it as an array, it will decay to a pointer in the `memcpy` call and blit the int array over top of the stack-(or static-)allocated struct array.

Alternatively, you could initialize `arr` with a call to `malloc(sizeof(num))`, but be sure to match such a call with a call to `free()`.

Also, as pointed out by comments, you need to pass `arr` and `num` rather than `&arr` and `&num`.  You want to copy the data, not the pointers (although it may be that `&num` is equivalent to `num` as a pointer, in this case).